# positioning buttons in div

Tags: php, html, css

So, im trying to position this buttons inside text, but it's moving cover image down and leaving blank wite space images, it should be in image, not move her down

Before:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqRB5.jpg

After:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgCKK.jpg

Code:

```
    <div class="covernebitno">
    <div class="avatar-profil"><a href="/index.php?action=profile">', $context['member']['avatar']['image'], '</a></center></div>
        <div class="usercover">
        <div class="dodajme-profil">
                <div class="profildugmad">  
        <a href="index.php?action=register" id="regsubmit">Send Message</a></br>
        <a href="http://noobot.info/uploader" id="regsubmit">Image Upload</a>
        </div>

<div class="informacije">

<p>'.$context['member']['name'].'</br><span class="bojeipticice">'.(!empty($context['member']['group']) ? $context['member']['group'] : $context['member']['post_group']). '</p>                    
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/U0TijfL.jpg" />

    <div class="covernebitno">

    </div></div></div>

            ';


css

.usercover 
 {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#99000000',GradientType=0 );

    width: 101%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

 .usercover img
 {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 250px;

    user-drag: none; 
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
}

.covernebitno {
    border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.avatar-profil img {
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 135px;
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.informacije p
{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 145px;
    margin-left: 135px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

.bojeipticice
{
    color: #696096;
}

.statusigraca
{
    color: #77513E;
}

.profildugmad
{
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.dodajme-profil {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `position: relative;` on your image and `position: absolute; z-index:999; top: 50px; left:50px` on the buttons;

Comment: nope, it's like this now http://pastebin.com/k96rCLxK

but this is how it looks http://i.imgur.com/OH0ohib.jpg

Comment: You should make a fiddle, and give us a link or something. Also,try to remove position relative on your image.